# FCM allows data storage of messages?

Tags: android, firebase, storage, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing a system where I have an android smart phone that receives data values from a sensor and shall upload this data to a Cloud, where some data processing shall occur and a response is sent back to the smart phone.

I've been reading about Firebase but I'm still confused, will I be able to implement such a behavior for the Cloud through it

1. stores received data in a database
2. does some operations on data received
3. responds with a customized reply I define

What I understood is I can use FCM, but does it allow me to store in a database the messages I received? and does it allow me to write a code to perform operations on the received data before sending a reply to the Smart Phone?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that's doable, you have two possibilities. Either integrate firebase on your Server or use [firebase queue](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/05/introducing-firebase-queue_97.html)

Also in order to respond to the device, you can either send notifications or use real time database from firebase.

Comment: I'll look into that!
Thanks alot :)
might ask you further when I get deeper into looking into them tho

Comment: To add a bit here, seems like your usecase can be satisfied with Firebase Database only. If you want to alert your application of some changes when it may not be running then you would want to look at FCM to do that.

Comment: But Arthur, I'm interested to have a backend logic at the Cloud, I mean I need to take the data received from the android side, store it in a data base, use it in some operations (as in hashing) then sending it back to the android side..
how do you think this shall be made possible?